# Error with Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener

I have a problem with layouts. I have one button in my main layout and another one in a second layout.

main layout:

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnclick);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
Shop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shop);
Shop.setOnClickListener(this);
```

second layout:

```
btnupgrade1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.u1btn);
Spiel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
```

But I can't set the buttons from the the second layout in the `OnClickListener`. I don't know why. Please help.

The coming error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:
    Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
        on a null object reference at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
```

Comment: Are you calling this method: setContentView()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `Button` on the second layout is null.

If you don't inflate the second layout, you can't **find** (`findViewById`) any `Views` on the layout.

While, maybe, the main layout is inflated by `setContentView(R.layout.main)` or something. So you can find some `Views` on it.

Make sure that your second layout is inflated.

Comment: Thanks <3 Now all is perfect